# Rotating mpg files

Tags: video-editing, rotate

I have got a couple of mpg files captured in a digital camera in a portrait mode. Are there any free tools to rotate to landscape them?

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows you can use [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/)

- open mpg
- in Video menu select filters
- click Add and select rotate,
- select rotation you want (left or right)
- you will need to select compression for the film, since VirtualDub doesn't support saving to mpg, you can only save as avi, so basically try different settings in Video menu --> Compress
- in File menu select Save as AVI to save the film

Comment: Thanks !!! The avi files are larger than the original files, but compressing them made them small.

Answer (score 0):

You can load them into Windows Live Movie Maker.  They have a rotate tool.